# Could I host my python code in Heroku, not webapps like flask, django

Tags: python, heroku

My problem: App hosted in HEROKU doesn't run
weather.py (simple code), not flask or django

Dear all, Im Loc, Im just new to python

My problem: App hosted in HEROK doesn't run

weather.py (simple code), not flask or django. App will not response for any http request

I already prepare
Profile
worker: python weather.py

requirements.txt

I push source code to Heroku successfully, but python file didn't work as I expect

I wonder if Heroku can host an app or only host webapp. I really need advice from you all

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Heroku can run non-web code. _Specifically_, what does "python file didn't work as I expect" mean? Is it crashing? Running, but giving unexpected results? What do you expect, and what is happening instead? Are you getting error messages in [your logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)? Please read [ask].

Comment: Dear Chris, "Heroku can run non-web code" , love to hear that, I see in the Log build successfully.

But Code doesnt work, Could you you please guide me to host simplest code like:
app.py
print("Hello World !")

Comment: Dear Chris, I export the log file, error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

My requirements.txt:

Comment: Finally, I resolved issue by myself, I missed only one command after pushing the code
heroku ps:scale worker=1

Comment: I'm glad you figured out that build-time logs (where the build succeeds) and runtime logs (where you see the error) are different things, and that you were able to find the relevant error message. The "your logs" link in my first comment goes to Heroku documentation showing how to view runtime logs.

Comment: Yes, you need to scale your dynos to the appropriate number. But that wouldn't fix the import error you reported from the logs. Are you entirely sure that the issue has been resolved?

Answer (score -2):

You have set the MONGODB_URI environment variable in Heroku to point to your MongoHQ database.
Add the code to the top of your Flask app:

```
import pymongo
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Get the MongoHQ database connection string
mongo_uri = os.environ.get('MONGODB_URI')

# Connect to the MongoHQ database
client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_uri)

# Store the database connection in the Flask app's context
app.context_processor(lambda: {'db': client.test})

# In your tweet consuming app, replace the code
 self.db = pymongo.MongoClient().test
#To
self.db = app.context['db']
# it will ensure that your app is using the same database connection as the Flask app.
```

Comment: I doesnt use from flask import Flask in my code
Source code will request a url to scrap news and export the link to GGsheet
I tested code before pushing to heroku, it works but not in Heroku

Comment: OP explicitly says they aren't using Flask, or any web framework. And what makes you think they're using MongoDB? Why do you think a missing `MONGODB_URI` environment variable is in any way relevant? Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure to address the question being asked.